# Having \includepdf overlap pages from different documents

Tags: tikz-pgf, pdfpages, overlap

Imagine I have a document A.pdf containing a page that looks as follows:
[image]
and a document B.pdf containing a page that looks like this:
[image]
If I write in my LaTeX document

```
\includepdf[pages={3}]{A.pdf}
\includepdf[pages={36}]{B.pdf}
```

I will get a new document containing the two pages above, as separate pages. Most of the time this is exactly what I want.

But this time I need the two pages to be merged, i.e., to overlap exactly, like this:
[image]

How can I obtain this? Is there some way to say “I would like page 3 from document A.pdf as my lower layer, and page 36 from document B.pdf as my upper layer, so that if B.pdf contains non-transparent parts, they will cover the corresponding areas in A.pdf but otherwise all contents of A.pdf and B.pdf will be visible in the same page, perfectly aligned”?

In terms of `\includegraphics` and single-page PDF documents, this would be equivalent to

```
\leavevmode\rlap{\includegraphics{page-from-A.pdf}}\includegraphics{page-from-B.pdf}
```

but I'm talking entire pages extracted from documents, as `\includepdf` does so nicely.

Is there some way to achieve this?

Maybe some other package than `pdfpages`, such as `tikz-pfg`?

Comment: Might the `textpos` package be helpful? I know it works for ordinary boxes, but not sure about pdfpages, if each pdfpage contains an instruction saying that it is a complete page.

Comment: it is trivial to put two pages one over the other. The main problem with pdfpages is that it scales and shifts the page around and it is not easy to track. If you know the sizes and where the pages should go the easiest imho would be to use the shipout hooks.

Comment: Let us imagine my whole target document C is made of superposed PDF pages from other documents A and B having exactly the same dimensions. Could you give me an example of shipout hook code to produce a superposed C page out of every pair of i-th A and B pages? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I think I found a solution: for documents with page width 8in, the following code worked:

```
\includepdfmerge[nup=2x1,delta={-7.125in 0cm}]{A.pdf,3,B.pdf,36}
```

The idea is to create a 2-page layout for the two pages I want to merge and then to add a negative delta so that they overlap. I have no idea where the value 7.125in came from, I found it by trial and error. It seems to work.

If someday the author of pdfpages decides to create a macro for this (something like `\includepdfoverlap` so that I don't need to do those calculations, I would appreciate it.

Thanks, rallg and Ulrike, for your help.