pdfpages includepdfmerge with noautoscale for one document but not for the other
When I use
\includepdfmerge[nup=2x1,delta={-17.525cm 0cm}]{A.pdf,1,B.pdf,1}

both documents get scaled to the paper limits, and when I use
\includepdfmerge[nup=2x1,noautoscale,delta={-17.525cm 0cm}]{A.pdf,1,B.pdf,1}

none of the two is scaled. How can I have one document autoscaled (or at least scaled by some factor given manually) and the other not?

Can you use two separate \includepdf instead?

How can I merge two different \includepdf in a single page? (see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/675809/having-includepdf-overlap-pages-from-different-documents)

You could use \includegraphics to include multiple different pdf with different scaling factors on a single page

It's not possible. Options of \includepdfmerge apply to each PDF. You cannot set options for certain PDFs individually.

Are you trying to superimpose things? What's the connection with your other question? Can you not provide code for a small example which would give people an idea of what you're doing and a basis for testing?
